# How to avoid passing a fixed-value array of large size to a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a function

```
               y=func(x,A)
```

where A is value fixed and of size about 1000x1000x10.  I need to call func many times. But every time I call the function, I need to pass A to it, which takes too much time. So, Is there a method that I need only pass A to the function only one time? Thank you very much.

I try to implement the funtcion as a class:

```
class fun_class():
      def __init__(self,A):
          self.A=A

      def func_1(self,x):
          return func(x,self.A)
```

But the runtime  did not decrease.

Comment: why don't you define it outside to functions and use it where needed without passing to a function?

Comment: Why C++? Targ spam?

Comment: You are on the right path. You can now simply access the array directly if the function you are trying to call is defined in the class. Otherwise you can modify your function a bit and use inline functions

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without knowing 
a) some more details of what `func` does
b) how this is being called (for loop?)

Comment: Please provide [mcve] your question doesn't make seance since as answer point out arrays are passed by reference in python. Adding tag `C++` was confusing - what was rationale behind that?

Comment: If something takes too long, it is not the argument-passing - the list isn't copied when you pass it.

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, it's not the argument-passing. I use Tensorflow to implent the function. I forgot to transorfom the numpy array to a tensor. After I transform it, the runtime decrease about 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing A to the function means passing a reference to A, and this takes almost zero time. Something else must make the function run slowly.